# How to move 'quick-access' div from header.phtml into topmenu.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.8, header

I'm wondering how to go about moving the 'quick-access' div into the nav-container below it?  When in the Chrome dev tools, I can drag the quick-access div into the nav container and it moves just as I want it to (admittedly it doesn't look great).

However, when I move the quick-access div from the header.phtml into the topmenu.phtml, the quick-access div just doesn't show up.

Anyone know how I can get it to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `quick-access` div look like this

```
    <div class="quick-access">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
        <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
    </div>
```

You moved it to `topmenu.phtml` which is a template of `page/html_topmenu`

As you can see it calls child blocks like

- topSearch
- welcome
- topLinks
- store_language

So you need to move theirs definition to page/html_topmenu block.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I ended up using this line in topmenu.html and it worked: <?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml()?>